# Different models in django-template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, view, django-mptt

I'm very new in Django and couldn't find solution for this. How can I pass 2 querysets from different models in 1 template? I use mptt categories and stack with it for awhile. I know that I have to make something with views.py but how can I combine these querysets? Here is my Models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey


class Variant(MPTTModel):
 category = models.CharField(max_length=500)
 logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
 slug = models.SlugField(max_length=160, blank=True, null=True)
 parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, 
  related_name='children', db_index=True,
                        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class MPTTMeta:
    order_insertion_by = ['category']

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'категория'
    verbose_name_plural = 'категории'

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('cosmetics:details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

def __str__(self):
    return self.category

def is_second_node(self):
        return True if (self.get_ancestors().count() == 1) else False



class Pic_Discription(models.Model):
 variant = TreeForeignKey('Variant', null=True, blank=True)
 model = models.CharField(max_length=500)
 pic_title = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
 description = models.TextField(default='')
 price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
 slug = models.SlugField(max_length=160,blank=True, null=True)
 available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Продукт'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Продукты'

def __str__(self):
    return self.model

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('cosmetics:details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Views.py

```
class CategoryView(generic.ListView):
model = Variant
template_name = 'cosmetics/homepage.html'

def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    """Get the context for this view."""
    queryset = object_list if object_list is not None else self.object_list
    page_size = self.get_paginate_by(queryset)
    context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(queryset)
    if page_size:
        paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
        context = {
            'paginator': paginator,
            'page_obj': page,
            'is_paginated': is_paginated,
            'object_list': queryset
        }
    else:
        context = {
            'paginator': None,
            'page_obj': None,
            'is_paginated': False,
            'object_list': queryset
        }
    if context_object_name is not None:
        context[context_object_name] = queryset
    context.update(kwargs)
    context['nodes'] = context.get('object_list')
    return super().get_context_data(**context)
```

Also I tried to add another class view for model but it doesn't work

```
class ProductsView(generic.ListView):
model = Pic_Discription
template_name = 'cosmetics/homepage.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Pic_Discription.objects.all()
```

My URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
#/cosmetics/
url(r'^$', views.CategoryView.as_view(), name='homepage'),
#/cosmetics/5/
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='details'),

url(r'^products/$', views.ProductsView.as_view(), name='products'),
]
```

Here is a template:

```
{% load mptt_tags %}

{% block body %}
   <div class="container-fluid2">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">

       <div class="panel panel-default" id="categories">
         <div class="panel-header" id="cat-head">Категории</div>
         <div class="panel-body" id="content-cat">
           {% recursetree nodes %}
                            <div class="
                                    {% if node.is_root_node %}
                                    root
                                    {% elif node.is_child_node and not 
                                  node.is_leaf_node or node.is_second_node%}
                                    child
                                    {% elif node.is_leaf_node and not 
                                    node.is_root_node%}
                                    leaf
                                    {%endif%}">
                                    {{node.category}}
                                </div>
                                {% if not node.is_leaf_node%}
                                <ul>{{children}}</ul>
                                {% endif %}
               {% endrecursetree %}
       </div>
       </div>
    </div>



        {% for cosmetic in object_list %}
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="{% url 'cosmetics:details' cosmetic.id %}">
                        {% if cosmetic.pic_title %}
                            <img src="{{ cosmetic.pic_title.url }}" class="img-responsive">
                        {% else %}
                            <h3>Изображение отсутствует</h3>
                        {% endif %}
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption" id="textyInfo">
                        <h2>{{ cosmetic.model }}</h2>
                        <!-- View Details -->
                        <a href="{% url 'cosmetics:details' cosmetic.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">
                            Подробнее
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% cycle '' '' '' '' '' '<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>' %}
        {% endfor %}



</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use context:

```
from .models import MyModel

...
context['my_model'] = MyModel.objects.all()
....
```

In your template, for example

```
{% for m in my_model %}
    {% m.myfield %}
{% enfor %}
```